# Resource [parameters('mgName')] Location must be an expression or 'global'

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-management-groups

I am experimenting with Azure Management Groups Arm template.

As you can see in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-to-management-group?tabs=azure-cli#management-group), I have this Arm template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-08-01/managementGroupDeploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "mgName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat('mg-', uniqueString(newGuid()))]"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Management/managementGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "[parameters('mgName')]",
      "scope": "/",
      "location": "eastus",
      "properties": {}
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "output": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('mgName')]"
    }
  }
}
```

Saved as `mg.json` and it works fine.

Later I start experimenting with validating and testing Arm template using `Test-AzTemplate` (https://github.com/Azure/arm-ttk). When I run following command to test Arm Template:

```
Test-AzTemplate -TemplatePath .\mg.json
```

I get this test error:

```
[-] Resources Should Have Location (3 ms)
    Resource [parameters('mgName')] Location must be an expression or 'global'
```

[image]

Now when I remove `"location": "eastus",` line form Arm template, the test does not fail and pass the test.

**My Question:**

Is this location in Management Group Arm required or not required? And why it is failing when it is part of Microsoft documentation! Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Location** is not required in Management Group. As you can check this Azure Create Management Group REST API [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/managementgroups/management-groups/create-or-update), location is not needed here.

*That's why in the template either you can remove the location or you can provide 'global' as the value, as the test command output specifies.*

Comment: I was not a aware of That part of doc. It seems this is a mistake by Microsoft doc in the one I provided